# Deterministic way to get column type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a computed column which uses a Scalar-valued Function to evaluate it's value. I need to make the column `Persisted` because of some reasons and to do it, I need to make that function deterministic. I use a query like the following to get the column type:

```
SELECT 
    @dataType = DATA_TYPE
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'X' AND
    TABLE_NAME = @TableName AND 
    COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnName
```

When I try to add `WITH SCHEMABINDING` clause to the function (to make it deterministic) I get the following error:

> Cannot schema bind function 'X.MY_FUNCTION' because it
>   references system object 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'.

How can I get the type of a column in a deterministic way? I looked into [COLUMNPROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columnproperty-transact-sql) and other Metadata functions but couldn't find a way to get the type of a column without using system objects.

Comment: What data type does the scalar function return? Why do you need to reference the data dictionary to determine what you should already know?

Comment: @Used_By_Already it returns `VARCHAR`. The function does some data formatting etc. according to the data type. I also get the column's length and other info too when making this formatting job. I didn't want to pass data type, length etc as parameter for each column

Comment: So I don't understand the question. You know the data type. To make it persisted you may have to give up on some of the "flexibility" you desire.

Comment: @Used_By_Already yes, I'm afraid so..

Comment: Deterministic means that it will always return the same result given the same parameters. This is not the case for your function as altering the table definition would alter the result.

Comment: @MartinSmith SQL Server's way to look into determinism is not 100% right imo. For a procedure/function, it looks if it's `schemabinding` and if it is, then it looks into that if the used functions fit into [these deterministic functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/deterministic-and-nondeterministic-functions). `FORMAT` for `datetime` is indeterministic in SQL Server for example (and it definitely is deterministic actually..). Why? Who knows. There are lots of functions which are actually deterministic but as for SQL Server indeterministic..

Comment: And as "David Browne - Microsoft" s answer stated, CLR TVFs are deterministic. Why? They had to be _always_ indeterministic imo. What I want to state by these examples is that SQL Server's way of detect determinism is not 100% bulletproof and I admit that I wanted a workaround for it (just like using a CLR TVF)..

Comment: Yep there are cases where deterministic things are treated as undeterministic. How is that relevant to the opposite case? If SQL Server was to treat your  function as deterministic and allow you to persist it then the persisted values would be rendered incorrect when you altered table.

Comment: @MartinSmith But that's what happens exactly in CLR TVFs. SQL Server says they are deterministic. What if the logic in the assembly changed?

Comment: Sure you can lie and claim that a CLR UDF is deterministic if it isn't but [Do not mark a function as deterministic if the function does not always produce the same output values, given the same input values and the same database state. Marking a function as deterministic when the function is not truly deterministic can result in corrupted indexed views and computed columns.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.isdeterministic(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I was just quoting that note :) These are dangerous waters i think. I would like to have no power to misguide SQL Server that my CLR TVF is deterministic whereas it's not. And checking whether an assembly function deterministic or not is not an easy task I know but allowing it to change with an [attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlfunctionattribute.isdeterministic.aspx)? It should have been always undeterministic i think because it might damage A"C"ID? But that's completely another issue :) But I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

For TSQL TVF's SQL verifies that the function is deterministic, but SQL Cannot verify that your function is deterministic if it access catalog views, because it cannot use SCHEMABINDING.

You can use a CLR TVF, which SQL doesn't completely verify, but will allow you to mark a CLR TVF as deterministic and use it in a persisted computed column.

Comment: +1d. That's a nice way actually but unfortunately it's not possible for me to add assemblies into sql server because of company policy

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this, but I'm not sure if this will help...

```
SELECT o.name,c.name,t.name,c.max_length,c.precision,c.is_nullable
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON c.object_id=o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.system_type_id=t.system_type_id
WHERE o.name=@YourTableName
  AND c.name=@YourColumnName
```

### UPDATE The worst case :-D

Nobody gave an answer yet... There seems to be no *generic* approach...

So think about this:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX);
WITH AllColumns AS
(
    SELECT c.TABLE_NAME AS tbl
          ,c.COLUMN_NAME AS col
          ,c.DATA_TYPE AS tp
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
)
SELECT @cmd=REPLACE
     ('CASE @tablename '
     + (SELECT ' WHEN ''' + c1.tbl + ''' THEN \n'
        +(
            SELECT 'CASE @columnname \n'
                 + (
                        SELECT ' WHEN ''' + c2.col + ''' THEN ''' + c2.tp + '''\n'
                        FROM AllColumns AS c2
                        WHERE c2.tbl=c1.tbl
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                   )
                 + ' END'
         )
        FROM AllColumns AS c1
        GROUP BY c1.tbl
        FOR XML PATH(''))
     + ' END','\n',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10));

--DROP FUNCTION GetColumnType;
SET @cmd='CREATE FUNCTION GetColumnType(@tablename VARCHAR(250),@columnname VARCHAR(250)) ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
       + 'RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
       + 'SELECT @tablename AS TableName,@columnname AS ColumnName,' + @cmd + ' AS DataType;';

EXEC(@cmd);
GO

SELECT * FROM GetColumnType('SomeTable','SomeColumn');
```

This will create an *inline TVF* with all the types you need. Whenever you change the structure of the database, you run this script (with a `DROP FUNCTION` first) again and everything is fine again.

Comment: Since `sys.columns` is a system object too, the error is the same. Cannot schema bind function 'X.MY_FUNCTION' because it references system object 'sys.columns'

Comment: If there would be a function to get it just like in `object_id(...)`.. But I'm afraid it doesn't exist..

Comment: @sotn If your tables and columns don't change, you might write all columns you are interested in with their types into a side table and read from there?

Comment: Yeah but that's my worst case scenario :)

Comment: @sotn No, the *worst case* was a (generated) *inline TVF* with a huge, hardcoded *`CASE WHEN` query* (might be very fast although...) :-D

Comment: @sotn See my update, the *worst of all worst cases* might be not so bad at last...

Comment: I just saw your update. I tested it now and it really is a hack, thanks for the effort :). But I needed to use this in a Scalar Valued Function but that `EXEC` statement is not allowed. I ended up writing a stored procedure which creates a computed column formula script which contains the data type, data length, precision etc as parameter to the function. I use that script to add my computed columns. I didn't want to hardcode hundreds of columns' data types, lengths etc. And as for performance, it works better now. Thanks

Comment: @sotn No, there is no need for EXEC. You do this only once. Than you can simply use the lightning fast function. Add this script as last step to any DB upgrade process and you will be fine forever